# Issue in OpenSQLConnect[MySQL[JDBC[Connector/J ...]

Tags: jdbc

Struggling with OpenSQLConnect[Connector/J] in Mathematica version 13.0. The code is:

```
OpenSQLConnection[
 JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "ip and name of remote database"], 
 "Version" -> 3.1, "Catalog" -> Automatic, "Description" -> None, 
 "autoReconnect" -> True, "Password" -> xxx", 
 "Properties" -> {}, "ReadOnly" -> Automatic, "RelativePath" -> False,
  "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> Automatic, 
 "UseConnectionPool" -> Automatic, "Username" -> "xxx", 
 "Timeout" -> 1000]
```

Getting:

```
*JDBC::error: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 515 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 484 milliseconds ago.*
```

Curious thing:

Executing the same code, at the same time, on the same machine in version 12.3 is working well.

Conclusion: it is a bug in 13.0.

Command JDBCDrivers["MySQL(Connector/J)"] gives

```
JDBCDriver["Name" -> "MySQL(Connector/J)", 
 "Driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", 
 "Protocol" -> {"jdbc:mysql://", "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://"}, 
 "Version" -> 3.1`, 
 "Description" -> "MySQL using Connector/J - Version 5.1.44", 
 "Location" -> 
  "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\12.3\\SystemFiles\\Links\\DatabaseLink\\
DatabaseResources\\mysql.m"]
```

the same as in version 13.0 (except the location)

```
JDBCDriver["Name" -> "MySQL(Connector/J)", 
 "Driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", 
 "Protocol" -> {"jdbc:mysql://", "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://"}, 
 "Version" -> 3.1, 
 "Description" -> "MySQL using Connector/J - Version 5.1.44", 
 "Location" -> 
  "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\13.0\\SystemFiles\\Links\\DatabaseLink\\\
DatabaseResources\\mysql.m"]
```

The mysql.m packages are identical in both installations. Verified on another computer, same behavior: v12.3 works, v13.0 doesn't.

Did anybody encounter this? Maybe a solution?

Thanks, Laszlo

Comment: I've encountered this as well, works in multiple versions of 12 but not 13.  Are you on 13.0.0 or 13.0.1?

Comment: -I've updated to 13.0.1 and the problem persists.  macOS 10.15.7

Comment: @atlasgeo Thanks for your reply. I have 13.0.0. Maybe we should fill a bug report?

Comment: Contacted Wolfram support and received a workaround. We must add Properties-> {useSSL-> False), to the command syntax. See below.

Comment: Thanks, I'd contacted them and referenced your post here, they redirected me back to this post for your answer lol.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram support suggested this workaround. See Properties->

```
OpenSQLConnection[
 JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "ip and name of remote database"], 
 "Version" -> 3.1, "Catalog" -> Automatic, "Description" -> None, 
 "autoReconnect" -> True, "Password" -> xxx", 
 "Properties" -> {"useSSL" -> "False"}, "ReadOnly" -> Automatic, "RelativePath" -> False,
  "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> Automatic, 
 "UseConnectionPool" -> Automatic, "Username" -> "xxx", 
 "Timeout" -> 1000]
```

It works! The developers will implement the useSSL->True in the next version.